# Struggling with $\limsup$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have that, for fixed $m$, 
$$
a_{n,m}<b_{n,m}\text{ for }n\geq 1-m
$$
and know that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln b_{n,m}=c.
$$

Do we then have that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln a_{n,m}<c
$$
or only that
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\ln a_{n,m}\leqslant c?
$$

Comment: Fourth installment of the same question, the first having already been answered with everything there is to say. Maybe this is enough, no? If you still do not get why $<$ is wrong and $\leqslant$ is ok, receiving again the same explanations and examples will not help. Please stop abusing the site.

Answer (score 0):

Let $b_{n,m} := \exp(n), a_{n,m} := \exp(n - 1)$ for all $m$. Then $a_{n,m}<b_{n,m}$ as well as $\frac 1n\ln a_{n,m} = 1-1/n < 1 = \frac 1n\ln b_{n,m}$.

But $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n\ln a_{n,m} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac 1n\ln b_{n,m}$. So it is only "$\le$", not "$<$".